Error Running Puppeteer in Docker Container on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) with hapi.js Microservice: PDF Generation and Download Failure
I've successfully generated and downloaded a PDF file using Puppeteer in my local environment. However, when attempting the same process within a Docker container on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using a hapi.js microservice, I encounter issues. We've defined multiple steps in our Dockerfile to run the microservice, with the final step being 'npm start'. I'm utilizing Puppeteer version ^21.1.1, hapi.js version ^20.0.3, and Node.js version 16.17.0. Can you assist me in resolving these issues?
Below is the error stack I am getting
DEFAULT 2024-04-15T10:22:50.209346Z Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 117.0.5938.92). This can occur if either
DEFAULT 2024-04-15T10:22:50.209353Z 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npm install) or
DEFAULT 2024-04-15T10:22:50.209357Z 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/.cache/puppeteer).
I tried to download & install chrome in docker file in one of step. I wanted to download pdf file in chrome browser.

Did you run npm install and make sure your cache path is correctly configured as the error suggests? This has also been asked before, so I'd check existing threads, like this, this, this.

yes I am doing npm install in docker file
